# Apigility content validator - enable to fetch service validator

Tags: zend-framework, laminas-api-tools

I was following the tutorials on https://apigility.org/documentation/content-validation/basic-usage. But, when I tried to inject the input filter service AddressBook\V1\Rest\Contact\Validator in the ContactResource, I get the following error:

`Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
File:
/Users/.../src/apigility-tutorials/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php:529
Message:
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for AddressBook\V1\Rest\Contact\Validator`

I am not sure if it's an issue with apigility itself, this is why i'm asking if the example shown in the link above actually works when using dependency injection. Thanks

Comment: Did you actually register an `InputFilter` with that name in your `InputFilterManager` or did you create `input_filter_specs` for a input filter with that name as a key?

Comment: @Wilt I used the apigility-admin interface to create this Contact REST service. I can confirm that it did create an input_filter_specs for Contact.

Comment: I read your question once more. What do you actually want to achieve? Why inject the `InputFilter` in the `ContactResource`?

Comment: @Wilt I was just following the tutorial on apigility documentation to set an example for my problem. My problem is that I cannot get the inputFilter service to work by calling `$service->get('AddressBook\V1\Rest\Contact\Validator')` in ContactResource or elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. According to the [zf-content-validation](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-content-validation) doc, the input filter is registered through `Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterPluginManager` which means I have to get the InputFilterManager service first then get the Contact input filter service as follows:

`$inputFilter = 
$serviceLocator->get('InputFilterManager')
               ->get('AddressBook\V1\Rest\Contact\Validator');`

Thanks for looking into it.